# strange certificate chain in website

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm new to site encryption and looking to expend my knowledge about certificates
while surfing online , I've stumbled on [this site](http://www.eset.com)

when looking on its `cert chain` it looks legit :

[image: eset certificate chain web]

but ... when I capture my `SSL handshake` with it , one of the certificates is missing : 
[image: eset certificate chain Wsh]

my question(s) are : 
1) how come browser sees cert chain depth 3 with all the details while `Wireshark` doesn't ?
2) how is it legit the the `root issuer` is not part of the chain ??

I've tested it using `Chrome` and `Explorer`

what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how come browser sees cert chain depth 3 with all the details while Wireshark doesn't ?

The browser shows the trust path to the locally stored root CA, including this root CA. wireshark showed the certificates sent by the server. While the leaf certificate will be the same the intermediate certificates (and root) might differ depending on what certifaces are trusted by the browser already.

> how is it legit the the root issuer is not part of the chain ??

The idea of certificate validation is that you never fully trust the peer, because the peer might by lying to you. Instead you have some local CA certificates (trusted root) and build a trust chain from these to the leaf certificate sent by the server. Only if this trust chain can be build the browser will believe that the server certificate is trustable. This means it is not only legit that the server does not send the root certificate but it is actually wrong if the server includes the root certificate in the chain. It should not harm much though because browsers will simply ignore this useless certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer ! but I've some issues with it : from what I saw till now in client with openssl API implementation: X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth(ctx) will throw error with depth 1 cert  : unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: @LordTitiKaka: I'm not really sure what you are trying to ask with this comment. But while it might be somehow related to your original question it looks more like a problem you have with a specific API, i.e. a different question. Thus please ask a new question and add enough context (code, error messages...).

Comment: I appreciate your comment and mark your answer as solution :)